# Автоматическая настройка высоты строк DataGridView'а

Tags: c#

Просьба помочь, никак не могу настроить экземпляр DataGridView, чтобы он изменял Высоту строк в соответствии с их содержимым. Пробовал AutoSizeRowMode ставить на AllCells, но он блокировал изменение высоты и при этом сам ее под содержимое ячеек строки не подгонял (использовал вместе с AutosizeColumnsMode Fill), DefaultCellStyle.Wrap ставил True, не получалось

Просьба помочь, заранее спасибо

UPD

[image][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"161" Не влазит, и так с любым количеством символов

Comment: В каком месте задаёте `AutoSizeRowsMode`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в свойствах экземпляра DataGridView. Пробовал через код, и как визуальный элемент на форме делать. Экземпляр.AutoSizeRowsMode
Но ни так, ни так не получалось

Comment: Лишь догадываюсь, что есть какое-то более приоритетное свойство, что перекрывает эту возможность

Comment: Есть 2 строки, у одной все влезает, у другой в одной ячейке не помещаются все символы, но они обе имеют одну высоту, хоть как уже и уточнял, свойство AutoSizeRowsMode стоит как AllCells

Comment: Не нужно гадать, нужно знать. Нет никакого более приоритетного свойства.

Comment: Дайте больше информации. Какой именно текст в ячейках? Банально скриншот приложите.

Comment: Давайте покажу, как нужно гадать: у вас нет переносов строки - `\r\n` - в тексте. поэтому он, естественно, тянется в длину.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Разве Auto не для того и Auto что это должно делаться само? Длина закреплена FIl'ом, я думал он должен сам перенос организовывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажу на примере.

Кладём на форму DataGridView.

Создаём и заполняем источник данных:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Columns.Add();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    dt.Rows.Add("aaa\r\nbbb", new string('x', 50));
```

Привязываем его к нашему гриду:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Если включить авторазмер строк:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

это ничего не изменит, т. к. пока что нет реакции на наличие переводов строк.
Добавим её:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Теперь высота строк изменилась (увеличилась) и в первой колонке отображаются две строки.
Содержимое второй колонки при этом по-прежнему автоматически не переносится.